# Using Rails with existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have an existing postgres database which gets populated by a python script. Now I am making a rails api which serves that data to a client. To my amusement all that I had to do is to create model classes and simply define relationships. No migration files, no schema, it just works. So a couple of questions.

- Am I right in saying that `schema.rb` is only needed for creating the
  database? If I am not running any migrations in my rails app I don't
  need any schema or migration files at all?
- I used to think that rails infers the names of model methods with the
  help of schema.rb . But it seems the only glue that ties ORM layer
  and the database is naming conventions? Are there any pitfalls I
  might be overlooking in doing things this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

schema.rb is indeed not required by ActiveRecord.

It is used for:

- having a quick overview of the state of the database
- creating thedatabase tables when using `db:schema:load` task
- in gems like [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment), (I think) it is used to create tenant specific schemas

TL:DR; - you don't really need schema.rb file but it's always good to have it as an authoritative source of db information.

More info here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you